# optional parameters for immutable classes

Tags: groovy

I am not sure whether this is the right forum to ask this question, but it refers to code, so I am asking here.

In the book "Groovy in action", section 7.1.4 (named parameters), the author says that usage of named params "crops up frequently in creating immutable classes that have some parameters that are optional".

What has immutability of the class got to do with optional parameters? I thought these 2 topics were completely orthogonal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key to that statement is that if you're dealing with an immutable class, the implication is that you have only one chance to set state - in a constructor.  Normally you'd be able to manipulate an (mutable) object via setters, one-at-a-time, to build up the desired state.  For an immutable, you'd have to create a ctor for every possible set of instantiation states instead, if a facility like optional params were not available.  For a class with many fields, this could get messy.

Answer (score 2):

> crops up frequently in creating immutable classes that have some parameters that are optional

the sentence above is a bit blurry as there is no such thing as "class parameters", i can only assume it relates to method/constructor parameters.

when we're talking about constructors, Groovy's named parameters make sense when its about optional parameters:

```
@groovy.transform.Immutable
class Person {

String firstName
String lastName
Integer age
}

def p = new Person(age: 42, lastName: 'Doe')
```

The above example shows how to create an immutable `Person` instance. The `firstName` is not provided as named parameter, it's optional. In fact, with named parameters it's possible to specify any parameter combo when making the constructor call without actually having to implement constructors for all combinations.

There is also the possibility of using named parameters in instance/static method calls, [as shown in this blog post by Mr. Haki](http://mrhaki.blogspot.co.at/2009/09/groovy-goodness-named-parameters-are.html).

Comment: Thanks, this part was also clear in the book. But my question was regarding the immutability of the class and its need for named params. Brian has answered this question below.